# Cannot drag UITextView to delegate methods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm stuck in this situation where I cannot link any **UITextView** delegate methods to my code, because they just don't show up in IB. That's all I've got :

[image]

I guess every delegate method should appear here (editingDidEnd, etc.) ?

UITextField delegates work fine though.

I also tried to create a `@IBAction func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {}` function manually, but I can't drag the UITextView to that function either.

Does someone know what is going on ?

Comment: If your object that is the delegate respects the UITextViewDelegate method, it would do it by itself. They are no IBAction, just implement them.

Comment: there will be simple delete shown in the IB,you just have connected that delegate, editingDidEnd etc...you will have to implement in the code manually and if you have made proper delegate connect that method will call, you can also set delegate programmatically

Comment: `MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate` + `myTextView.delegate = self` + `func textViewDidEndEditing(_:)`

Comment: A delegate method does not work as a target - action mechanism. Instead you just set the delegate to point to the controller of your choice and then make the controller conform to the delegate protocol by implementing the delegate methods.

Comment: I naively thought that `UITextView` works in the same manner as `UITextField`. Thanks a lot guys.